# Gremlin: remove repeated parent edges

Tags: gremlin

My Query:

```
g.V().has("a","123").has("s","1").has("e","p").has("r","e-1").repeat(outE().where(values("startTime").is(gte("2018-12-15"))).where(values("endTime").is(lte("2018-12-16"))).otherV().simplePath()).emit().path().by(valueMap("a","s")).fold()
```

I am getting result as

A-->B

A-->B-->C

A-->B-->C-->D

How do I remove the first 2 lines from the output?

Desired output:  A-->B-->C-->D

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't emit the paths in the first place.

```
edgeTraversal = outE().
           has("startTime", gte("2018-12-15")).
           has("endTime", lte("2018-12-16")).simplePath(); []
g.V().has("a","123").has("s","1").has("e","p").has("r","e-1").
  repeat(edgeTraversal.clone().inV()).
    until(__.not(edgeTraversal)).
  path().
    by(valueMap("a","s")).fold()
```

Without the child traversal variable:

```
g.V().has("a","123").has("s","1").has("e","p").has("r","e-1").
  repeat(outE().
           has("startTime", gte("2018-12-15")).
           has("endTime", lte("2018-12-16")).simplePath().inV()).
    until(__.not(outE().
                   has("startTime", gte("2018-12-15")).
                   has("endTime", lte("2018-12-16")).simplePath())).
  path().
    by(valueMap("a","s")).fold()
```

Comment: I get an exception, If I use this.
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: edgeTraversal for class: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal.

tried `def edgeTraversal`as well

Comment: I don't know which graph DB you're using and thus why it's not working, but you can always just duplicate the query and get rid of the variable. I'll add this to my answer.